# Value of future depends on whether it has been bound to a variable?

Tags: scala, future

Code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

/**
  * Created by IDEA on 12/23/16.
  */
object Demo extends App {
  val fut = Future {
    Thread.sleep(100)
    21 + 21
  }
  val f = Future { 5 }
  Thread.sleep(200)
  val fut1 = fut.map(_ + 1)
  println(fut1) // Future(Success(43))
  println(fut1.value) // Some(Success(43))
  println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
  fut.map(_ + 1).onComplete {
    case Success(v) => println(v)
    case Failure(e) => println(e)
  } // 43

  (for {
    x <- Future {Thread.sleep(100); 21 + 21}
    y <- Future {Thread.sleep(100); 21 + 22}
  } yield x + y).andThen {
    case Success(v) => println(v)
  }
  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Note the difference between:

```
println(fut1.value) // Some(Success(43))
println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
```

i.e., retrieving the value of future after assigning it to a variable gives me a `Some(Success(43))`, while retrieving it directly gives `None`. Why?

Also note that the `onComplete` method produces the expected behavior, although it was called after the `println(fut.map(_ + 1).value)` line.

Scala 2.12.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fut.map(_ + 1)` returns a new `Future`, whose `.value` may not have been completed yet. If it hasn't, then you get the `None` the `println` shows, otherwise you'll get `Some(Success(43))`.

You can see this in the REPL:

```
// Paste the body of your Demo object before
// Then repeatedly call the last println:

scala>   println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
Some(Success(43))

scala>   println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
None

scala>   println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
Some(Success(43))

scala>   println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
Some(Success(43))

scala>   println(fut.map(_ + 1).value) // None
None
```

**Edit**:
Showing the non-deterministic results of your code (without any changes to it):

```
scala> Demo.main(Array())
List()
None
Some(Success(43))

scala> Demo.main(Array())
List()
None
None

scala> Demo.main(Array())
List()
None
None

scala> Demo.main(Array())
Success(43)
Some(Success(43))
Some(Success(43))
```

Comment: Sleeping the main thread doesn't seem to help at all on my machine. Could you confirm this in a scala `App`?

Comment: @qed: I'm not sure what you mean. A `Thread.sleep` without assigning the `.map` result won't affect anything, and assigning it sort of contradicts the question.

Comment: @qed: I added the output of 4 runs of your code to show that it isn't always the same.

Comment: Ah, I got it. `fut.map(_ + 1).value` immediately retrieves the value without much waiting for the future to complete. Sleeping the main thread should indeed have no effect here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've just hit a timing issue because you're not properly waiting for the futures to complete.  When running the last computation in the Scala REPL, it gives actually sometimes prints `None`, sometimes `Some(Success(43))`.

If however, you e.g. ran:

```
fut.map(_ + 1).onComplete {
  case Success(v) => println(v)
  case Failure(ex) =>
}
Thread.sleep(100)
```

It would always print 43. You'll need to ensure your program doesn't terminate before the future is complete of course to see the result.

Comment: On my machine, even sleeping the thread for 5 seconds doesn't help.

Comment: Should be `onComplete` by the way. `onSuccess` is deprecated.

Comment: Where was your `Thread.sleep` for 5s, did you try it after the code I pasted, i.e. at the end of the program? Yep, looks like you're right; `onSuccess` is deprecated in Scala 2.12.

Comment: OK. This works for me, and based on your edited question it looks like this works for you, too.